# How to stop use of other views behind a slide out menu in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, menu, slide, out

I have a slide out menu that with a swipe gesture slides in and out from the left on top of a table view I have. But when the menu is out I can still select cells and scroll through the table view that the menu slides out on top of.

any help would be cool thanks

Comment: hi 
i faced the same problem, so did you solve it ?
if yes please tell us 
thanks so mush

Comment: @eng_rawan unfortunatly I never came up with a good solution, the various things mentioned below did not work in my case. I resulted in using Quartzcore and placing the menu at the front, then practically filled the screen with the menu. I tried creating a mask layer to go behind the menu (whilst making it slimmer shaded for effect) and tried to stop pressing through the mask, but this also didn't work. If I find a solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set "setExclusiveTouch:YES" on the SlideMenuView.

From The iPhone OS Programming Guide:

Restricting event delivery to a single view:

> By default, a view’s exclusiveTouch property is set to NO. If you set the property to YES, you mark the view so that, if it is tracking touches, it is the only view in the window that is tracking touches. Other views in the window cannot receive those touches. However, a view that is marked “exclusive touch” does not receive touches that are associated with other views in the same window. If a finger contacts an exclusive-touch view, then that touch is delivered only if that view is the only view tracking a finger in that window. If a finger touches a non-exclusive view, then that touch is delivered only if there is not another finger tracking in an exclusive-touch view.

Comment: I can not seem to get xcode to accept "setExclusiveTouch" are you sure it is not deprecated. I also read that this only stops touching other views whilst your finger is touched down the exclusive view.<br>Thanks though man any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi, no it is not deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/exclusiveTouch You have to set this on the slideMenuView!

Comment: Oh wow sorry i looked for setExclusiveTouch and it said deprecated. Thanks man appreciate it.

Comment: @OliverM hi 
in my app i put the gesture on the tableview not on the side menu, so i couldn't use your solution.
so any other idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `QuartzCore`

```
import QuartzCore

/* .. */

slideOutMenu.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Your slideOutMenu will be top of UITableView.

Comment: Thank for your help, this work for placing the view above the tableView but i need to figure a way of stopping the user from selecting the tableview that behind it. The menu slides out around half way leaving some of the origin table view visible.  Thanks for your help though man I appreciate it